# $\mathrlap{\cdot}\lrcorner$

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I was using

```
\newcommand*{\pb}{\mbox{\LARGE{$\mathrlap{\cdot}\lrcorner$}}}
```

and put

```
\arrow[dr, phantom, "\pb", very near start]
```

in `tikz-cd` code to indicate a pullback square. It works well in my previous LaTeX but does not now, it looks like:

[image]

The dot goes too much to the left when it should be in the middle of the `lrcorner`. How to fix this?

Comment: Please post a complete MWE. Are you loading the `mathtools` package? For what it's worth, we could also draw that symbol with just TikZ. Also, `\large` is a switch, not a argument-ed macro. (No difference in this case but syntactically weird.)

Comment: OK, thank you! I added `mathtools` and it's now good

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have gotten an error about an undefined control sequence:

```
<recently read> \mathrlap 
                          
l.8 \end{tikzcd}
                
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

The package `mathtools` that provides `\mathrlap` is missing.

---

Since `\LARGE` is also not a macro that takes on argument but just switches the font size I've adjusted the definition of `\pb` accordingly.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}   % for \lrcorner
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathrlap
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand*{\pb}{\mbox{\LARGE$\mathrlap{\cdot}\lrcorner$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[dr, phantom, "\pb", very near start] \\
& B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]